# Material-UI on iPhone: Phantom topClick Events Closing Dialog Element?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a [Material-UI `<Dialog>` element](http://www.material-ui.com/) that has worked perfectly for a long time, including in Chrome using device emulation. Recently I noticed that for some reason, when using device emulation in Chrome, the dialog opens, and then immediately closes. The same thing is happening with my `<Drawer>` element. Looking at the call stack, I can see a `topClick` event is triggering `dispatchEvent` and is closing the elements -- even though I've clicked nothing except the UI element that opens the Dialog or Drawer.

When I am not using device emulation, everything runs as expected.

The same anomaly is seen when I access the web app from my iPhone. I have updated to the latest versions of all my React plugins, including `react-tap-event-plugin`, but the anomaly is still here.
What could be causing this?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info!

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI has dropped its dependency on `react-tap-event-plugin`. It now uses `onClick` instead of `onTouchTap.`